# How do I enable horizontal two-finger scrolling in Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS?

Tags: 20.04, touchpad

Hi guys I can't seem to be able to find a solution to this. I see someone recommended 'libinput' but apparently it's already installed by default

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

Go inside a Terminal: and type:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad two-finger-scrolling-enabled true
```

If not; please reply and tell me what went wrong!

#### Edit:

```
sudo apt install mate-settings-daemon
```

and then:

```
 gsettings set org.mate.peripherals-touchpad horizontal-two-finger-scrolling true
```

Does this work for you?

//Regards

Comment: I have entered the command looks like it went through however it has not activated the horizontal scroll

Comment: Oh okay thanks for replying so quickly , wait 1 min

Comment: by the way two finger vertical scroll works fine it's just the horizontal scroll

Comment: Oh; right - thanks for the detail:  then I guess I know what I'm looking for, will come back

Comment: @Matt_eo88 Try my updated answer, hopefully it works by now :)

Comment: Thank you for your help unfortunately it's still not working! installation  completed and run the commands no error message

Comment: @Matt_eo88 Weird ... I unfortunately can't do much more I think;    I'm sorry;  (I will continue trying on my Ubuntu) but I do hope some expert just comes along and solves this :/   //Regards